# Parse.com Query for PFUser CurrentUser

Tags: ios, uitableview, parse-platform, pfquery

Hello to everyone in the query I posted I'm trying to retrieve all of the posts and PfUserCurrent all posts of people who have shared a friendship with PfUserCurrent.

The query works fine but I have only one problem, the query shows me all the posts of Friends of the CurrentUser but does not show me those sent by the CurrentUser ... I've tried several attempts but I could not fix this ... Can you explain where I'm wrong?

```
-(void)QueryForPost {

    PFQuery *QueryForFriend=[PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Friendships"];
    [QueryForFriend whereKey:@"To_User" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
    [QueryForFriend whereKey:@"STATUS"  equalTo:@"Confirmed"];



    PFQuery *QueryYES = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Post"];
    [QueryYES whereKey:@"FLASH_POST" equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
    [QueryYES whereKey:@"UserSelected" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];


    PFQuery *QueryNO = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Post"];
    [QueryNO whereKey:@"FLASH_POST" equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
    [QueryNO whereKey:@"Author" matchesKey:@"From_User" inQuery:QueryForFriend];

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:@[QueryYES,QueryNO]];
    [query includeKey:@"Author"];

    [query orderByDescending:FF_CREATEDAT];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"%@", results);
            ArrayforPost = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            for (PFObject *object in results) {
                [ArrayforPost addObject:object];
            }
            [self.FFTableView reloadData];
        }
    }];



}
```

Comment: It's Italian, so it's very difficult for me to understand your database schemes. You should give us more details about your database scheme :)

Comment: Can you try to add this `[QueryForFriend includeKey:@"Da_User"]` under your `QueryForFriend queries`. This might be problem if `Da_User` is a pointer

Comment: BabyGau Hello and thank you for your answer: D
I edited the post trying to put all the letters of the database in English to make you understand better ... I also tried to add your advice (includekey Da_User) but it did not work ... the time the user current posts do not appear ... : ((((

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with your query. I put my doubt on this line `[query orderByDescending:FF_CREATEDAT];` where `FF_CREATEDAT` might be not match with key `createdAt` in `POST` class. Is `ArrayforPost` a datasource of `FFTableView`???

Comment: It ArrayforPost is' NSMutableArray used in Tableview ....

My whole problem goes away if I remove this line [QueryForFriend whereKey: @ "To_User" equalTo: [PFUser currentUser]];

So I view the post also the time the user Current the problem is that if I remove this line the current user sees the post of all subscribers to the app and this is not good because it should only read the posts of his friends as in normal social network ...
Adding this line posts are filtered and displayed only a friend's post but it seems that the posts do not appear CurrentUser

Comment: So you want the result to displays all posts of current user and his friend only, right?

Comment: The app will post the time the user must return all current and his friends .. only this

Comment: I can't help u now coz thing u want to achieve still confuse me. It's 1:00 am now, I will text you via twitter when I'm free tmr (from 10:00 am) if you want. Because it will be better if I can chat with you to break down more details

Comment: you certainly ... if you can help it would be great .... I am waiting for your call ... I also leave you my email so I know when you are free info@neographic.it

Comment: Sure mate, I'm glad if I could help. Good night

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a long discussion with @rory, here we come to the correct answer:

```
-(void)QueryForPost {

PFQuery *QueryForFriend=[PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Amicizie"]; 
[QueryForFriend whereKey:@"A_User" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]]; 
[QueryForFriend whereKey:@"STATO" equalTo:@"Confermato"]; 
[QueryForFriend includeKey:@"Da_User"]; 

PFQuery *QueryYES = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Post"]; 
[QueryYES whereKey:@"FLASH_POST" equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]]; 
[QueryYES whereKey:@"Scelti" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]]; 

PFQuery *normalPostByFriends = [PFQuery queryWithClassName: @"Post"]; 
[normalPostByFriends whereKey: @"FLASH_POST" equalTo: [NSNumber numberWithBool: NO]]; 
[normalPostByFriends whereKey: @"Utente" matchesKey:@"Da_User" inQuery:QueryForFriend]; 

PFQuery *normalPostByUser = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Post"]; 
[normalPostByUser whereKey: @"FLASH_POST" equalTo: [NSNumber numberWithBool: NO]]; 
[normalPostByUser whereKey: @"Utente" equalTo: [PFUser currentUser]];

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:@[QueryYES,normalPostByFriends,normalPostByUser  ]];
[query includeKey:@"Author"];

[query orderByDescending:FF_CREATEDAT];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", results);
        ArrayforPost = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (PFObject *object in results) {
            [ArrayforPost addObject:object];
        }
        [self.FFTableView reloadData];
    }
}];

}
```

The problem is handled by making another query to display current user's normal post and modify `QueryForFriend` for a correct query

Comment: Thanks again for everything you're always very helpful and kind!